# Custom images for HTMLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, air

There is powerful `HTMLLoader` component for AIR wrapped in `mx:HTML` for Flex.

I want to supply images manually (ideally from bytes) for `mx:HTML,` which will display my generated content. The point is to pack all resources in the application without external files. I can pack different html pages in the app and switch them when `mx:HTML` dispatches `Event.LOCATION_CHANGE.` Now I want the same for images. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!** Went through several stages:

1. Make HTMLLoader's background transparent with `paintsDefaultBackground="false"` and `backgroundAlpha="0"`. Get notified of pictures location with javascript and draw them on HTMLLoader's graphics. This is complex and has problems with resizing (pictures get shifted), but was almost done...
2. Next idea - use <canvas> to draw images on them, sending data to javascript.
3. While reading canvas tutorials, stumbled upon [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%3a_URL), which does exactly what I needed in simplest possible way. Images are embedded in html page in base64 encoding.